# Copy the RDS tags to it attached security Group in powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-rds

I am working on a task where I have to copy the tags of RDS database instance to its attached RDSdb Subnet group. It is possible..?? And I am not able get tags of RDS subnet group in  powershell cmdlets.

Kindly help

Comment: Hello Sigh, could you add what have you tried, and why that dint work?

Comment: for started I was not able to find any cmdlets to get the tags of rds subnet group.